# React-Native iOS: Hide the text input bottom tool and autosuggest bar

Tags: ios, react-native

My text input field searches over unique content that never matches auto-suggest and doesn't need undo/redo functionality. Is there a way to hide this bar in react-native for iOS? I have `spellCheck` and `autoCorrect` both set to `false` but as shown in the image below, the bar remains only without those features.

I want to hide the whole thing. It is covering my interface!

Alternatively, I could move the UI up by that height when the text field is in focus, but I was hoping to avoid that.

[image: Toolbar]

Answer (score 1):

BRyan! try setting `autoComplete="off"` as well. You might also want `autoCapitalize="none"` for this use case.

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you. The `autoComplete="off` doesn't have an affect, but turning off `autoCapitalize` is a nice touch. Thanks for the partial answer.